# How to write a DAG connecting with Amazon Redshift?

Tags: airflow

Say I want to write a DAG to show all tables in a specific schema of Redshift.
The `SQL` query is `Show Tables;`

How do I create the DAG for it?
I assume this should be something like:

```
dag = airflow.DAG(
    'process_dimensions',
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60),
    default_args=args,
    max_active_runs=1)

process_product_dim = SQLOperator(
    task_id='process_product_dim',
    conn_id='??????',
    sql='Show Tables',
    dag=dag)
```

Does anyone know how to write it correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you want to return the result of that query and not just execute it, you'll want to use the PostgresHook, specifically the [`get_records`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/dbapi_hook.py#L98) method.

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.hooks import PostgresHook

def process_product_dim_py(**kwargs):
    conn_id = kwargs.get('conn_id')
    pg_hook = PostgresHook(conn_id)
    sql = "Show Tables;"

    records = pg_hook.get_records(sql)

    return records

dag = DAG(
    'process_dimensions',
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60),
    default_args=args,
    max_active_runs=1)

process_product_dim = PythonOperator(
    task_id='process_product_dim',
    op_kwargs = {'conn_id':'my_redshift_connection'}
    python_callable=process_product_dim_py,
    dag=dag)
```

Comment: Thx. What if I also wanted to execute a query? For example TRUNCATE TABLE ?

Comment: If you just want to execute a query (without returning results), you could change the above from `records = pg_hook.get_records(sql)` to `pg_hook.run(sql)` but it would be simpler to cut out the PythonOperator entirely and use the PostgresOperator. - https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/postgres_operator.py#L24

Comment: How to pass result from select sql operator to the next operator in dag? Is a XCOM a bad idea for tables?

example of select operator
https://gist.github.com/fpopic/35807489d9c36c7ea8bc4de6f966b5fc#file-select_postgres_operator-py-L40-L42

Comment: @fpopic - it depends how sensitive your data is and how large the result is. Anything passed as an XCOM will be stored persistently in the XCOM table. For larger/sensitive datasets, I recommend writing to a local file (if just a single node) and passing the location as an XCOM or writing to S3/GCS/etc and passing the key path as the XCOM.

Comment: So then one operator will do A_to_B and another will do B_to_C, for example if I would like to copy a Postgres table (A) to BigQuery (C) via GCS (B). Probably that's the reason why https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/tree/master/airflow/contrib/hooks there are a lot of operators like X_to_Y using X, Y hooks.